# matplotlib negative value inverted

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

Hi Everyone I am new to python I m trying to plot an array called `rx` this array goes from  -45.7 to  -119 in y axis and distance as well is an array of floats between 1 and 3000 as x axis

when I do `plt.plot(distance, rx)`
it seems the curve is inverted normally `rx` should decrease as distance increases

any idea what may causes the problem thank you
[image]

Comment: Convert your strings to floats

Comment: try doing `rx = rx[::-1]` before plotting and let us know what happens